# I know it's been asked before, but I can't figure out why resizeable isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen a few threads here about the resizeable() function in JQuery not working but they usually seem to come down to not including the css. I'm including the CSS but something is still wrong and I've spent days trying to figure out what. Any help? Simplified version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script> $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() { $("#test").resizeable(); }); }); </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="test" src="http://i.imgur.com/lrdy4jc.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the method is `.resizable()` not `.resizeable()`

Comment: This was even more frustrating than I could possibly have imagined.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

works great for me......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").resizable();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="test" src="http://i.imgur.com/lrdy4jc.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

ouchy `resizable()` spelling